# Can I remove a directory “Cancer ” and leave all other sub directories intact for directory “/home/John/Cancer/MillionDollars”?. Bash / Linux

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

Get rid of  directory “Cancer” but keep directory “Million Dollars”

```
           Directory:   /home/John/Cancer/MillionDollars 
   Desired Directory:  /home/John/MillionDollars
```

This is for later versions of Linux

Thank you 
Timfox123

Comment: Use the `mv` command, then remove the `Cancer` directory?

Comment: "Questions must demonstrate a **minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See *[How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608/126632)* for further guidance."

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a Linux guru, but I'm going to guess that you have to move `MillionDollars` to `John` first before you delete `Cancer.`

`mv /home/John/Cancer/MillionDollars /home/John/MillionDollars`

`rm -r /home/John/Cancer/`

Comment: Don't worry, you don't have to be a Linux guru to answer this one. :-p